# Is my application cache manifest file legal for my website or will I run into a cross-domain policy issue?

Tags: cache, application-cache

I'm trying to figure out if I can reference subdomains in a cache manifest file and have the assets cached. I read that in SSL mode (which I'm not using on my site) all URLs must be referenced from the same domain. Does this also apply if I serve pages from the HTTP protocol (non SSL)?

I read information from here: http://appcache.offline.technology/

If you need an example of what I'm trying to accomplish, let's start with my domain setup:

```
http://i.example.com - domain for all assets including images
http://example.com - domain for HTML
```

And this is my proposed cache manifest file that I will locate at http://i.example.com/manifest:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# last updated 
http://i.example.com/decoration
http://i.example.com/another-decoration
NETWORK: *
```

and http://i.example.com/manifest will be callable from a page within http://example.com

I'm just wondering if my cache manifest file is legal or will i run into a cross-domain policy issue?

Comment: You keep knocking 'em outta the park!!

Comment: Well google is in love with high-speed. I must say since the multi-domain merge my income went up a bit, but the UX improvements didn't boost my income (yet). Now if only I can get my site to load faster and use the manifest efficiently without having to break my only remaining subdomain in use,  then I'll have a site probably faster than google. LOL